# How to efficiently find all combinations of the letters in an alphabet given a condition

Tags: performance-tuning, expression-manipulation, algorithm, combinatorics

### Problem:

I want to find all unique expressions with `n` number of terms that contain all the digits (or characters) in `alphabet`.

**Example**: Let the variable `alphabet` be a given a `List` of digits or characters (for now let us use base 10 or the output of `Range[0, 9]`).
So I need all equations with non repeating digits, as follows:

[image: Each one of these has the digits from 0-9]

Note that each one of the multiplications above contains all the digits without repetition from 0  to 9.

For example: `402 * 39 == 15678` contains `{4,0,2,3,9,1,5,6,7,8}` - all unique elements of alphabet `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`.

### Solution: Draft

```
alphabet = (  ToString /@ Range[0, 9]  );
Off[Part::partw];
(
 uniqueTerms[  alphabet_List: (ToString /@ Range[0, 9] ), 
 size_Integer: Part[Divisors[alphabet_], 2], 
selectionCriteria_: _] := 
   (*  Select returns a list of elements that match a given pattern. *)
   Select[
     DeleteDuplicates /@ Permutations[alphabet, {size}]
   , selectionCriteria] 

  ) ;

(  twos = uniqueTerms[ alphabet, 2, ! SameQ[#[[1]], "0"] & ] );
(  threes = uniqueTerms[alphabet, 3, ! SameQ[#[[1]], "0"] & ]   ) ;
(  expressions = Select[ Flatten[  Table[ 
      {  threes[[  i  ]], twos[[  j  ]] ,
       DeleteDuplicates[  
        Flatten[ { threes[[  i  ]], twos[[  j  ]] }  ]  ]  },
      {  i, Range[Length@threes]  },
      {  j, Range[  Length@twos  ]  }
      ], 1] , Length[  #[[  3  ]] ] == 5 &  ]  [[  
   All, {  1, 2  }  ]]  ) ;
 (  eqns = ( 
   expressions //. {a_List, 
      b_List} :> {t1 = FromDigits[ToExpression /@ a], 
      t2 = FromDigits[ToExpression /@ b], t1*t2} ) ) ;
sol = SortBy[  
   Select[eqns, (  
       IntegerDigits[ #[[1]] ] \[Union] 
        IntegerDigits[ #[[2]] ] \[Union] IntegerDigits[ #[[3]] ] ) == 
      Range[0, 9]  & ], Last] /. {a_, b_, c_} :> 
   TraditionalForm[a\[Cross]b == c]
```

This was my solution. I would like to use an alternative to `Permutations` and `Select` in cases where `alphabet` is big enough (maybe using `Signature` and `PartitionQ` or `` Combinatorica`TransitiveReduction ``).

Any suggestion to generalize or improve my approach is welcomed. Links to similar problems, posts, books and articles are also helpful.

Comment: `! SameQ[#[[1]], "0"]`  in `uniqueTerms[alphabet, 3, ! SameQ[#[[1]], "0"]`.

Comment: That is because in `uniqueTerms[  alphabet_List: (ToString /@ Range[0, 9] ), 
 size_Integer: Part[Divisors[alphabet_], 2], selectionCriteria_: _]`  is called as the defalt value of the second argument. It does not affect functionality.

Comment: I saw `Select[Permutations[Range[0, 9]], FromDigits[Take[#, 3]]* FromDigits[Take[#, {4, 5}]] == FromDigits[Take[#, -5]]&]` and it is interesting  but `16` seconds is quiet big. The approach I proposed took `1` second.

Comment: Also because the product have to have at least as many digits as the number of digits in the factors  we do not consider `01 * 345 == 1 * 345 -> {1, 3,4,5}`  because that will give us an answer with less than 5 digits and therefore the expression will not contain all the characters in the alphabet.   Remember  `402 * 39 == 15678` is `True` and `{4,0,2,3,9,1,5,6,7,8} == {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` is also `True`.

Answer (score 6):

You draft code gives on my PC `1.11 s`. This version is better (the best I've got so far is `0.26 s`), though `Permutations` preserved (I cannot see how to avoid them efficiently):

```
({p2, p3} = DeleteCases[Permutations[Range[0, 9], {#}], {0, __}] & /@ {2, 3};
  list = Flatten[Outer[Join, p3, p2, 1], 1];
  tmp2 = (FromDigits[#] & /@ list[[All, 1 ;; 3]])*(FromDigits[#] & /@ list[[All, 4 ;; 5]]);
  list2 = IntegerDigits /@ tmp2;
  res = Select[DeleteDuplicates /@ MapThread[Join, {list, list2}], Length[#] == 10 &];

 (* view *)

  tmp3 = Transpose[{FromDigits[#] & /@ res[[All, 1 ;;  3]], 
                    FromDigits[#] & /@ res[[All, 4 ;;  5]], 
                    FromDigits[#] & /@ res[[All, 6 ;; 10]]}];

  SortBy[tmp3, Last] /. {a_, b_, c_} :> TraditionalForm[a\[Cross]b == c]) 
// RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

> ```
> res= {{2, 9, 7, 5, 4, 1, 6, 0, 3, 8}, {3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 2, 6, 9, 1, 0}, 
>       {3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 1, 9, 0, 8, 4}, {3, 9, 6, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 2, 0}, 
>       {4, 0, 2, 3, 9, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {4, 9, 5, 3, 6, 1, 7, 8, 2, 0}, 
>       {5, 9, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 0, 3, 8}, {7, 1, 5, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 9, 0}, 
>       {9, 2, 7, 6, 3, 5, 8, 4, 0, 1}}
> ```

**Edit**
With `Case` instead of `Select` timing is better - (`0.26 s`):

`res = Cases[Replace[Range[0, 9], _ :> _, {-1}]][
  DeleteDuplicates /@ MapThread[Join, {list, list2}]]`

Comment: @Schopenhauer, note that your code without `ToString`  inclusions gives `0.84` on `RepeatedTiming` test. I've also found no way to use `PackedArray` in the example provided.