# Puzzle with Mathematica

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

[image: puzzle]

Hello everyone,
This is a puzzle I got from someone via social media. Basically, we need to fill up the boxes with the numbers 1-9 (no repetitions) that fit the multiplication and addition operations.

I managed to solve this puzzle by using a brute force method in Excel+VBA. However, it would be very interesting if it can be solved in *Mathematica* with its specialty as computational software. Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a chinese btw.. I'm just guessing from the '1-9' and the the nine empty boxes.. :)

Comment: Similar [topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105960/how-to-efficiently-find-all-combinations-of-the-letters-in-an-alphabet-given-a-c/106025#106025)

Comment: I need serious help regarding Mathematica. I am learning it as recreational tool (plus it helps me in financial modeling) that is why I'm interested in puzzles being solved in Mathematica because I can learn more easily the language. However I did not understand anything happening above, except for part of @xiang 's reply as it contained the operations (x,+ and -) but nothing more. Where can I learn the language to be able to formulate solutions like I have seen above. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A **non brute-force** approach is the following, similar to my answer for the [Zebra Puzzle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47211/elegant-solution-to-the-zebra-logic-puzzle-einsteins-riddle).

Both puzzles are examples of constrainst satisfaction problems, that can be solved with `Reduce`/`Minimize`/`Maximize` or, more efficiently, with `LinearProgramming`.

The good about this approach is that you can easily extend and apply to many similar problems.

The common part:

- Assign an index $i$ to each box from top left, $i=1,2,\ldots,9$.
- In each box you should put a digit $k$, $k=1,\ldots,9$.
- Assign an index $l$ to the whole number/row, $l=1,\ldots,5$.
- the variable `x[i,k]` is $1$ if there is the digit $k$ in the cell $i$ and $0$ otherwise.
- `d[i]` is the digit in cell $i$.
- `n[l]` is the whole number in the row $l$ (one or two cell).

---

The easier and slower approach is with `Maximize`. Build constraints and pass to `Maximize` with a constant objective function, so `Maximize` will try only to satisfy constraints. Constraints are:

- `n[1] * n[2] == n[3]`
- `n[3] + n[4] == n[5]`
- each cell should be filled with exactly one digit
- each digit should be placed in exactly one cell
- `0 <= x[i,k] <= 1`, `x[i,k] \elem Integers`

That's all.

```
d[i_] := Sum[x[i, k] k, {k, 9}]
n[l_] := FromDigits[d /@ {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}[[l]]]

solution = Last@Maximize[{0, {
      n[1]*n[2] == n[3],
      n[3] + n[4] == n[5],
      Table[Sum[x[i, k], {k, 9}] == 1, {i, 9}],
      Table[Sum[x[i, k], {i, 9}] == 1, {k, 9}],
      Thread[0 <= Flatten@Array[x, {9, 9}] <= 1]}},
    Flatten@Array[x, {9, 9}], Integers];

Array[n, 5] /. solution
```

> {17, 4, 68, 25, 93}

Not fast (not linear).

---

A faster approach is to use `LinearProgramming`, but you need to:

- change the first constraint so that it become linear
- manually build matrix and vectors input for `LinearProgramming` (see docs)

The next piece of code do that. Please note that the single non-linear constraint `n[1]*n[2] == n[3]` has been replaced with 18 linear "conditional" constraints.

```
d[i_] := Sum[x[i, k] k, {k, 9}]
n[l_] := FromDigits[d /@ {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}[[l]]]

vars = Flatten@Array[x, {9, 9}];

constraints = Flatten@{
    Table[{
      k n[1] >= n[3] - 75 (1 - x[3, k]),
      k n[1] <= n[3] + 859 (1 - x[3, k])
      }, {k, 9}],
    n[3] + n[4] == n[5],
    Table[Sum[x[i, k], {k, 9}] == 1, {i, 9}],
    Table[Sum[x[i, k], {i, 9}] == 1, {k, 9}]};

bm = CoefficientArrays[Equal @@@ constraints, vars];
solution = LinearProgramming[
   Table[0, Length@vars],
   bm[[2]],
   Transpose@{-bm[[1]], 
     constraints[[All, 0]] /. {LessEqual -> -1, Equal -> 0, 
       GreaterEqual -> 1}},
   Table[{0, 1}, Length@vars],
   Integers
   ];

Array[n, 5] /. Thread[vars -> solution]
```

> {17, 4, 68, 25, 93}

The execution is now about instantaneous.

Answer (score 14):

Can't think out a better method than brute force, it'll be conciser in *Mathematica* of course:

```
g = 10 # + #2 &;
Pick[#, g[#, #2] #3 == g[#4, #5] == g[#8, #9] - g[#6, #7] & @@@ #] &@Permutations@Range@9
```

> ```
> {{1, 7, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3}}
> ```

Comment: You could use `g = FromDigits @ {#1, #2 } &` and make it `g[ #1, #2 ] #3 ...` for readability maybe?

Comment: @gwr I was just trying to make the code as concise as possible. ( Since I failed to think out a better method, I decided to make the answer distinctive in some way :D )

Answer (score 11):

To make the *brute force* solution a bit more pleasant for the eye of the observer:

```
testFunc = And[
   FromDigits @ {#1, #2} #3 == FromDigits @ {#4, #5},
   FromDigits @ {#4, #5} + FromDigits @ {#6, #7} == FromDigits @ {#8, #9}
]& ;

sol = Range[9] // RightComposition[

    Permutations,
    SelectFirst[ testFunc @@ # & ]

]
```

> {1, 7, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3}

Answer (score 9):

```
Range[9] // Permutations // 
  Select[(10 #[[1]] + #[[2]])*#[[3]] == 10 #[[4]] + #[[5]] &] // 
 SelectFirst[
  10 #[[4]] + #[[5]] + 10 #[[6]] + #[[7]] == 10 #[[8]] + #[[9]] &]
```

So,17*4=68；68+25=93。

好玩吧

Answer (score 4):

A relatively fast one (ugly though)

```
Module[{x = Permutations@Range@9, y},
 y = Pick[x, 
  (10 x[[All, 1]] + x[[All, 2]]) x[[All, 3]] - 10 x[[All, 4]] - x[[All, 5]], 0];
 Pick[y,
   10 y[[All, 4]] + y[[All, 5]] + 10 y[[All, 6]] + y[[All, 7]] - 10 y[[All, 8]] - y[[All, 9]], 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but just wanted to play:

```
a = Range[9];
can = {#, Complement[a, #]} & /@ 
   Select[{##}~Join~IntegerDigits[(10 #1 + #2) #3] & @@@ 
     Select[Permutations[
       a, {3}], (10 #[[1]] + #[[2]]) #[[3]] < 100 &], 
    Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] && FreeQ[#, 0] &];
fun[a_, b_] := Module[{perm = Permutations[b], res},
  res = a[[4 ;; 5]].{10, 1} + #[[1 ;; 2]].{10, 1} == #[[3 ;; 4]].{10, 
        1} & /@ perm;
  {a, Pick[perm, res]}
  ]
DeleteCases[fun @@@ can, {_, {}}]
```

yields:

```
{{{1, 7, 4, 6, 8}, {{2, 5, 9, 3}}}}
```